# FastText quantize documentation incorrect?

Tags: fasttext

I'm unable to run FastText quantization as shown in the documentation.  Specifically, as shown at the bottom of the cheat sheet page:

https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/cheatsheet.html

When I attempt to run quantization on my trained model "model.bin":

```
./fasttext quantize -output model
```

the following error is printed to the shell:

```
Empty input or output path.
```

I've reproduced this problem with builds from the latest code (September 14 2018) and older code (June 21 2018).  Since the documented command syntax isn't working, I tried adding an input argument:

```
./fasttext quantize -input [file] -output model
```

where [file] is either my training data or trained model.  Unfortunately both tries resulted in a segmentation fault with no error message from FastText.

What is the correct command syntax to quantize a FastText model?  Also, is it possible to both train and quantize a model in a single run of FastText?

Comment: If your trained model is "model.bin", so pass it: `./fasttext quantize -output model.bin`

Comment: Hi did you get a solution to this problem? I tried to quantize a pre-trained word embedding following the command and I get the same error...

Comment: Yes, I figured it out after banging on it for quite a while.  The documentation was incorrect.  Here's an example with some optional arguments:

`./fasttext quantize -input training_examples -output model_without_extension -cutoff 2000000 -dsub 8 -retrain`

The critical issue is the model filename (model_without_extension).  This must be the model filename without an extension.  Otherwise it will load the wrong file and segfault.

Answer (score 2):

Solution in Python:

```
# Quantize the model with retraining
model.quantize(input=train_data, qnorm=True, retrain=True, cutoff=200000)

# Save quantized model
model.save_model("model_quantized.bin")
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this one worked:

```
 ./fasttext quantize -input <training set> -output <model name (no suffix) -[options]
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the example that is included in the `quantization-example.sh`

```
./fasttext quantize -output "${RESULTDIR}/dbpedia" -input "${DATADIR}/dbpedia.train" -qnorm -retrain -epoch 1 -cuto$
```